Oracle DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE for merge stmt
I have used Oracle DBMS pkg for parallel execute and it works fine.
Now i am trying to use to run a simple MERGE stmt. Its giving me all kinds of errors. I tried the same pkg create_chunks_by_rowid and create_chunks_by_number_col all of them errors out.
My question is can it(DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE pkg) handle a merge stmt or what am i doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.
BTW the merge sql stmt runs fine when run in sql.
Given below is the merge stmt that i tried using and getting errors from the pkg.
CREATE TABLE test_tab (
  id          NUMBER,
  description VARCHAR2(50),
  num_col     NUMBER,
  session_id  NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT test_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO test_tab
SELECT level,
       'Description for ' || level,
       CASE
         WHEN MOD(level, 5) = 0 THEN 10
         WHEN MOD(level, 3) = 0 THEN 20
         ELSE 30
       END,
       SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'',''SESSIONID'')
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 1000000;
COMMIT;

create table test_tab2 as select * from test_tab;

delete from test_tab where rownum<500001;
commit;

exec DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task (task_name => 'test_task');
exec DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => 'test_task');

SELECT DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.generate_task_name
FROM   dual;

set serverout on;
DECLARE
l_stmt  varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  l_stmt := 'MERGE into test_tab2 b
            using test_tab a
            on (a.id=b.id)
            when matched then 
                update set b.session_id = a.session_id
            when not matched then
                insert (id,description,num_col,session_id)
                values(a.id,a.description,a.num_col,a.session_id)';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_sql(task_name => 'test_task',
                                             sql_stmt  => l_stmt,
                                             by_rowid  => FALSE);
                                            
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE", line 373
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1641
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE", line 324
ORA-06512: at line 13
01007. 00000 -  "variable not in select list"
*Cause:    
*Action:


Don't use that package, it's much too cumbersome. Just enable parallel dml and hint the query:
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session enable parallel dml';

    MERGE /*+ parallel(b,16) append */ into test_tab2 b
            using test_tab a
            on (a.id=b.id)
            when matched then 
                update set b.session_id = a.session_id
            when not matched then
                insert (id,description,num_col,session_id)
                values(a.id,a.description,a.num_col,a.session_id);
    COMMIT;
END;

As long as you have available parallel servers and there isn't something in the table (like enabled foreign keys) that is incompatible with parallel dml, this is much easier to work with. When executing, examine the SQL plan actually in use per ASH or SQL monitor and ensure that the PX Coordinator process is above the merge step. If so, you've achieved parallel DML and you're good to go.
